# Sql Server query not giving correct results

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 3 tables in Sql server. Following is the structure of the tables.

[image]

The employee table will contain list of employees. Project table will have list of Projects. Mapping table will have mapping between employee and Project and hours for each week ending. The mapping table will not have mapping for all employees and project for all week Endings.
I need to join the 3 tables and get the Result of all the employees for a Particular Project within a week ending. If a Particular employee is not having hours for this weekending, the employee details should come but the hours should come as 0.

[image]

I have the below query, but it is showing only the employee who is having the weekEnding value in the mapping table.

```
    SELECT RT.EMP_ID,RT.EMP_NAME, RT.EMP_EMAIL_ID, RPM.WEEK_ENDING, RPM.RSC_HOURS_LOGGED
 FROM vl.rsrc_prjct_hrs_mapping RPM  right outer Join vl.resource  RT ON RT.EMP_ID = RPM.EMP_ID 
 JOIN 
 vl.project PT ON PT.PROJECT_ID=RPM.PROJECT_ID WHERE PT.PROJECT_IRM='TMPT-4854' AND
  PT.PROJECT_DESC='33801-Urgent Care EnhancementEPDS V2' AND 
  RPM.WEEK_ENDING BETWEEN '2018-07-07' AND '2018-08-07';
```

But I want all the employees, but the week Ending should come and hours should be 0.

I also tried using the below query :

```
select RT.EMP_ID,RT.EMP_NAME, RT.EMP_EMAIL_ID,tt.week_ending,tt.RSC_HOURS_LOGGED from vl.resource  RT left outer join (select RPM.EMP_ID,RPM.WEEK_ENDING, RPM.RSC_HOURS_LOGGED from vl.rsrc_prjct_hrs_mapping RPM join vl.project PT ON PT.PROJECT_ID=RPM.PROJECT_ID WHERE PT.PROJECT_IRM='TMPT-4854' AND PT.PROJECT_DESC='33801-Urgent Care EnhancementEPDS V2' AND RPM.WEEK_ENDING BETWEEN '2018-07-07' AND '2018-07-07') tt on RT.EMP_ID = tt.EMP_ID;
```

But this is giving all the employees in the employee table, but I want only the employees for a particular project.

Comment: Move the RPM conditions from WHERE to ON.

Comment: @jarlh can you please modify the query and give me? I am not able to get what you are saying

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. Please use text, not images/links, for text, including tables & ERDs. Show what parts you can do. Learn what outer join on returns: inner join on rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. PS This is a faq easily found by googling clear, concise, precise statements of your question/problem/goal.

Answer (score 0):

`RIGHT OUTER JOIN` with `JOIN` converted to `INNER JOIN` implicitly thus right outer join has no use here. Change the order of your joins or make both of outer join

Also you need to move `RPM.WEEK_ENDING BETWEEN '2018-07-07' AND '2018-08-07'` to `ON` clause of the `Right outer join`

```
SELECT 
   RT.EMP_ID,
   RT.EMP_NAME, 
   RT.EMP_EMAIL_ID, 
   RPM.WEEK_ENDING, 
   RPM.RSC_HOURS_LOGGED
FROM vl.rsrc_prjct_hrs_mapping RPM  
right outer Join vl.resource  RT 
  ON RT.EMP_ID = RPM.EMP_ID and
  RPM.WEEK_ENDING BETWEEN '2018-07-07' AND '2018-08-07'
... OUTER JOIN vl.project PT 
  ON PT.PROJECT_ID=RPM.PROJECT_ID  and 
     PT.PROJECT_DESC='33801-Urgent Care EnhancementEPDS V2' AND
     PT.PROJECT_IRM='TMPT-4854'
```

Comment: I tried this query :  SELECT 
   RT.EMP_ID,
   RT.EMP_NAME, 
   RT.EMP_EMAIL_ID, 
   RPM.WEEK_ENDING, 
   RPM.RSC_HOURS_LOGGED
FROM vl.rsrc_prjct_hrs_mapping RPM  
right outer Join vl.resource  RT 
  ON RT.EMP_ID = RPM.EMP_ID 
 full outer JOIN vl.project PT 
  ON PT.PROJECT_ID=RPM.PROJECT_ID  and 
     PT.PROJECT_DESC='33801-Urgent Care EnhancementEPDS V2' AND
     PT.PROJECT_IRM='TMPT-4854'
where 
  RPM.WEEK_ENDING BETWEEN '2018-07-07' AND '2018-07-07';  But the result is coming for this week ending for all the projects. I want only for a particular project

Comment: can you please provide sample data and expected output :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend using `right join`.  It is just confusing.  Use `let join` -- keep all rows in the first table and matching rows in the subsequent tables.

So, if you want to keep all employees, then start with that table:

```
SELECT RT.EMP_ID, RT.EMP_NAME, RT.EMP_EMAIL_ID, RPM.WEEK_ENDING, RPM.RSC_HOURS_LOGGED
FROM vl.resource RT LEFT JOIN
     vl.rsrc_prjct_hrs_mapping RPM 
     ON RT.EMP_ID = RPM.EMP_ID AND
        RPM.WEEK_ENDING BETWEEN '2018-07-07' AND '2018-08-07' LEFT JOIN 
     vl.project PT
     ON PT.PROJECT_ID = RPM.PROJECT_ID AND
        PT.PROJECT_IRM = 'TMPT-4854' AND
        PT.PROJECT_DESC = '33801-Urgent Care EnhancementEPDS V2' ;
```

The filtering on the project goes into the `ON` clause.

If you want only people who have *ever* been on the project, then you need additional filtering.  I think this will do what you want:

```
SELECT RT.EMP_ID, RT.EMP_NAME, RT.EMP_EMAIL_ID, RPM.WEEK_ENDING, RPM.RSC_HOURS_LOGGED
FROM vl.resource RT LEFT JOIN
     vl.rsrc_prjct_hrs_mapping RPM 
     ON RT.EMP_ID = RPM.EMP_ID AND
        RPM.WEEK_ENDING BETWEEN '2018-07-07' AND '2018-08-07' LEFT JOIN 
     vl.project PT
     ON PT.PROJECT_ID = RPM.PROJECT_ID AND
        PT.PROJECT_IRM = 'TMPT-4854' AND
        PT.PROJECT_DESC = '33801-Urgent Care EnhancementEPDS V2'
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM vl.rsrc_prjct_hrs_mapping RPM2 JOIN
                   vl.project PT2
                   ON PT2.PROJECT_ID = RPM2.PROJECT_ID AND
                      PT2.PROJECT_IRM = 'TMPT-4854' AND
                      PT2.PROJECT_DESC = '33801-Urgent Care EnhancementEPDS V2'
              WHERE RPM2.EMP_ID = RF.EMP_ID 
             );
```